# How to pass c# value to Html Page using parameter in ASP>NET C#

Tags: c#, html

Hi i have values in c# and i want to transfer this value to Html page by using parameter. here what i did

C#:::

```
protected void btnPreviewEmail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string body = string.Empty;
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("~/EmailTemplate/ExportJobsEmailTemplate.html")))
    {
        body = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
    body = body.Replace("{jobnumber}", txtJobNo.Text);
}
```

HTML Page ::::

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <b>Job Number</b>
        </td>
        <td>{jobnumber}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This is now how C# works. Try to explore Web Technologies using this link - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/modern-web-apps-azure-architecture/common-client-side-web-technologies

Comment: can you give me a solution because not understood using this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/modern-web-apps-azure-architecture/common-client-side-web-technologies Thanks @Sahil Sharma

Comment: Is this HTML on aspx page ?

Comment: Is this HTML on aspx page  : yes

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this by.

First initialize your server side variable as public

```
 public string YourText;
```

Then in your code

```
YourText = body.Replace("{jobnumber}", txtJobNo.Text);
```

and finally in HTML put

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <b>Job Number</b>
    </td>
    <td>'<%=YourText%>'</td>
</tr>
```